# Kubernetes POD running on Jenkins slave is getting restarted, nothing else happening

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

The Kubernetes POD running on the Jenkins Slave is getting restarted. It is just repeating, nothing else. Kubernetes cluster is running in AWS. Can someone help, what exactly happening here. I am running a simple pipeline which I found in GitHub (https://github.com/vivid-lukeloresch/test-pipeline).  Here are the console logs. Thanks for all help.

```
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git https://github.com/vivid-lukeloresch/test-pipeline.git
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] readTrusted
Obtained build-pod.yaml from git https://github.com/vivid-lukeloresch/test-pipeline.git
[Pipeline] podTemplate
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] node
Created Pod: default/promo-app-gn5v8-w05qg
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-w05qg][Scheduled] Successfully assigned default/promo-app-gn5v8-w05qg to ip-192-168-9-82.ec2.internal
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-w05qg][Pulling] Pulling image "maven:3.5.4-jdk-8-slim"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-w05qg][Pulled] Successfully pulled image "maven:3.5.4-jdk-8-slim"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-w05qg][Created] Created container maven
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-w05qg][Started] Started container maven
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-w05qg][Pulling] Pulling image "docker:18.06.1"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-w05qg][Pulled] Successfully pulled image "docker:18.06.1"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-w05qg][Created] Created container docker
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-w05qg][Started] Started container docker
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-w05qg][Pulled] Container image "jenkins/jnlp-slave:4.0.1-1" already present on machine
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-w05qg][Created] Created container jnlp
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-w05qg][Started] Started container jnlp
Still waiting to schedule task
‘promo-app-gn5v8-w05qg’ is offline
Created Pod: default/promo-app-gn5v8-3527t
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-3527t][Scheduled] Successfully assigned default/promo-app-gn5v8-3527t to ip-192-168-81-238.ec2.internal
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-3527t][Pulling] Pulling image "maven:3.5.4-jdk-8-slim"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-3527t][Pulled] Successfully pulled image "maven:3.5.4-jdk-8-slim"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-3527t][Created] Created container maven
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-3527t][Started] Started container maven
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-3527t][Pulling] Pulling image "docker:18.06.1"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-3527t][Pulled] Successfully pulled image "docker:18.06.1"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-3527t][Created] Created container docker
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-3527t][Started] Started container docker
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-3527t][Pulled] Container image "jenkins/jnlp-slave:4.0.1-1" already present on machine
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-3527t][Created] Created container jnlp
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-3527t][Started] Started container jnlp
Created Pod: default/promo-app-gn5v8-hqr5z
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-hqr5z][Scheduled] Successfully assigned default/promo-app-gn5v8-hqr5z to ip-192-168-81-238.ec2.internal
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-hqr5z][Pulling] Pulling image "maven:3.5.4-jdk-8-slim"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-hqr5z][Pulled] Successfully pulled image "maven:3.5.4-jdk-8-slim"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-hqr5z][Created] Created container maven
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-hqr5z][Started] Started container maven
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-hqr5z][Pulling] Pulling image "docker:18.06.1"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-hqr5z][Pulled] Successfully pulled image "docker:18.06.1"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-hqr5z][Created] Created container docker
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-hqr5z][Started] Started container docker
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-hqr5z][Pulled] Container image "jenkins/jnlp-slave:4.0.1-1" already present on machine
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-hqr5z][Created] Created container jnlp
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-hqr5z][Started] Started container jnlp
Created Pod: default/promo-app-gn5v8-7zn32
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-7zn32][Scheduled] Successfully assigned default/promo-app-gn5v8-7zn32 to ip-192-168-9-82.ec2.internal
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-7zn32][Pulling] Pulling image "maven:3.5.4-jdk-8-slim"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-7zn32][Pulled] Successfully pulled image "maven:3.5.4-jdk-8-slim"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-7zn32][Created] Created container maven
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-7zn32][Started] Started container maven
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-7zn32][Pulling] Pulling image "docker:18.06.1"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-7zn32][Pulled] Successfully pulled image "docker:18.06.1"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-7zn32][Created] Created container docker
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-7zn32][Started] Started container docker
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-7zn32][Pulled] Container image "jenkins/jnlp-slave:4.0.1-1" already present on machine
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-7zn32][Created] Created container jnlp
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-7zn32][Started] Started container jnlp
Created Pod: default/promo-app-gn5v8-jsgzn
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-jsgzn][Scheduled] Successfully assigned default/promo-app-gn5v8-jsgzn to ip-192-168-9-82.ec2.internal
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-jsgzn][Pulling] Pulling image "maven:3.5.4-jdk-8-slim"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-jsgzn][Pulled] Successfully pulled image "maven:3.5.4-jdk-8-slim"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-jsgzn][Created] Created container maven
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-jsgzn][Started] Started container maven
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-jsgzn][Pulling] Pulling image "docker:18.06.1"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-jsgzn][Pulled] Successfully pulled image "docker:18.06.1"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-jsgzn][Created] Created container docker
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-jsgzn][Started] Started container docker
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-jsgzn][Pulled] Container image "jenkins/jnlp-slave:4.0.1-1" already present on machine
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-jsgzn][Created] Created container jnlp
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-jsgzn][Started] Started container jnlp
Created Pod: default/promo-app-gn5v8-zskvd
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-zskvd][Scheduled] Successfully assigned default/promo-app-gn5v8-zskvd to ip-192-168-81-238.ec2.internal
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-zskvd][Pulling] Pulling image "maven:3.5.4-jdk-8-slim"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-zskvd][Pulled] Successfully pulled image "maven:3.5.4-jdk-8-slim"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-zskvd][Created] Created container maven
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-zskvd][Started] Started container maven
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-zskvd][Pulling] Pulling image "docker:18.06.1"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-zskvd][Pulled] Successfully pulled image "docker:18.06.1"
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-zskvd][Created] Created container docker
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-zskvd][Started] Started container docker
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-zskvd][Pulled] Container image "jenkins/jnlp-slave:4.0.1-1" already present on machine
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-zskvd][Created] Created container jnlp
[Normal][default/promo-app-gn5v8-zskvd][Started] Started container jnlp
```

Comment: Check every created container's logs and the corresponding machine's kubelet log and syslog

Comment: add pod yaml in the question

Comment: I am just following JenkinsFile file and .Yaml provided in this GitHub repository https://github.com/vivid-lukeloresch/test-pipeline

Comment: Hi zerkms, could you provide me an easy way to get the logs for the container? My k8S cluster is EKS. And my Jenkins master is running on standalone ec2 Linux machine.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the Jenkins slave can't initialize. Most likely because it can't connect to the Jenkins master.

Make sure your slave/pod can connect to the value of `JENKINS_URL`.  You can start another pod on the same namespace and see if you have any connectivity issues:

```
$ kubectl run -i --tty --rm debug --image=ubuntu --restart=Never -n <namespace-where-the-jenkins-pods-are-running> -- sh
```

You can also look at the logs while the pod is running for the specific containers.

```
$ kubectl -n <namespace-where-the-jenkins-pods-are-running> logs -c <container-name> <pod-name>
```

For example:

```
$ kubectl -n default logs -c jnlp promo-app-gn5v8-w05qg
```

Comment: Thanks, Rico.  I allowed inbound traffic for the "TCP port for inbound agents" port on the Jenkins Master and all started working. Thanks you..